# Pass command-line result as an argument to next command

Tags: command-line, terminal

Trying to insert output from this:

```
kubectl get pods | grep -Eo '^[^ ]+' | grep portal
```

Into this:

```
kubectl exec -it <here> portal bash
```

Tried:

```
kubectl exec -it `kubectl get pods | grep -Eo '^[^ ]+' | grep portal ` portal bash
```

But no luck.

Comment: What does "no luck" mean? Did you get some kind of error? Does the command in the command substitution return the correct thing? What happens if you use `... -it "$(...)" ...` instead of the backticks (quoting is difficult with backticks).

Comment: @Kusalananda It says:
Defaulting container name to portal-container.
Use 'kubectl describe pod/portal-74767c88b-92sct' to see all of the containers in this pod.
rpc error: code = 2 desc = oci runtime error: exec failed: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "exec: \"portal\": executable file not found in $PATH"

In both cases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
kubectl exec -it "$(kubectl get pods | grep -Eo '^[^ ]+' | grep portal)" bash
```

Or, even more:

```
kubectl exec -c portal-container -it "$(kubectl get pods | grep -Eo '^[^ ]+' | grep portal)" bash
```